# Adding unique index to a MySQL text field string using hashing in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, hash, unique

I have a Rails app with a model (table) that has 1,500,000 records, with text field size ranging from 50 to 8000 characters.

I need to ensure that a text field is unique. Since I can't use MySQL unique index on text field, my solution is to convert my text field into a hash ( using Digest::SHA256.hexdigest) and save this hash into a varchar field called "body_hash". Then add a unique index, on that field.

Questions:

- I was wondering if there is built-in solution in Rails for this? ( Rather than me reinventing the wheel - so far I couldn't find anything. )
- Is another hashing algorithm better to use here than Digest::SHA256.hexdigest for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Rails solution is a `before_save` hook. You could also do this with a database trigger but that's a lot more messy and brittle.

SHA256 is probably fine here, as it's SHA2-based. The chance of a collision should be vanishingly small.

Using a consistent length hash instead of the text for the unique index is actually a great idea because MySQL's indexes get larger for longer strings. A short hex-string is a lot easier for the indexing engine to handle and still provides the uniqueness constraint you want.

MySQL's unique constraints actually provide an ordering mechanism as well, that's the source of pain here, but if you aren't concerned with ordering the hash solution is a great alternative.

Comment: One downside of a `before_save` hook is that it doesn't protect one from inserts / updates made directly in the DB

Comment: @oldp Sometimes that's a feature, sometimes that's a liability. When you need to bypass this behaviour at least you have options if it's done in the application layer. Doing it at the DB layer can be far more difficult to circumvent if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider generating this checksum / digest in the DB itself. This would be faster to back fill values for existing data rather than process in Ruby.

Combining MySQL's `CREATE_DIGEST` to populate a `body_digest` column:

```
CREATE_DIGEST('SHA512', 'The quick brown fox');
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enterprise-encryption-functions.html#function_create-digest

And an `BEFORE INSERT` / `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to set this checksum value:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Worth mentioning there's a Ruby library for declaring database triggers on ActiveRecord models:
https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger